# Can a virus spread through DOSBox in Ubuntu?

Tags: antivirus, viruses, dosbox

I have a virus in several DOSBox msdos games. It doesn't seem to be affecting the Ubuntu files, but is spreading amongst my dosfiles that were opened in DOSBox. I don't know how to control this in the DOSBOX emulator, but ClamAV found them on a routine scan of my `/home` folder. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

From a security standpoint, if you've got games running on DOSBOX, Wine, or otherwise that have viruses, trojans, worms, or other things, you should just remove them instantly and purge any other files they may have touched.  That'd be my suggestion.

Comment: Because whether they affect Ubuntu or not is irrelevant :P

Answer (score 0):

Dosbox apps can access and modify files from mounted directory only, So probablity of affecting virus via dosbox is very less. Still it is better to remove viruses for better security

Comment: Not "from mounted directory only", but "in the Dosbox directory only". The words have different meanings.

Comment: ^I mean dosbox apps

Answer (score 0):

You can run a "boot disk" anti-virus solution, but there's no telling how well it will handle an emulated environment. You can try [one of these antivirus boot disks](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/system-security/tp/free-bootable-antivirus-software.htm) and see if that gets rid of your viruses.

As far as your main question: there's too much we don't know. Ubuntu is very tight in security and most viruses won't be Linux compatible, but there are viruses out there that can cause you problems.